# Indicating fill pieces in a script

Tags: screenwriting

I'm writing a script that involves an interview with a person a la *60 minutes* or *Behind the Music*. I'm a little confused if the "fill pieces" should be formatted as "recorded" or "prerecorded" in its slugline.

> Alexa Jones interviews John Baker.
>
> ```
>                                  Alexa 
>                          Lets talk about your greenhouse.
> ```
>
> They laugh.
>
> ```
>                                  John 
>                          Sure, lets.
>                                                     CUT TO: INT. GREENHOUSE - DAY (RECORDED)
> ```
>
> Alexa and John walk through John's futuristic greenhouse.

Would that slugline be in the right ballpark?

Comment: Recorded makes little sense for a script. It will all be recorded. V/O or V.O. for voice over is used much more.

Answer (score 1):

After CUT TO: the next scene heading should be on its own line.

> CUT TO:
>
> INT. GREENHOUSE - DAY (PRE-RECORDED)

I'd say "(PRE-RECORDED)" instead of "(RECORDED)".

After the clip, I think you need a BACK TO SCENE
to return to the live interview.